# convert c++ string to char array

Tags: c++, string

I would like to convert a `string` to a `char array` so I can pass it into a function which requires `const char nameToAssignToChannel[]` to be passed to it.  Here is something I have tried:

```
string example;

example = "examplestring";

char *converted = new char [example.length()+1];

strcpy(converted, example.c_str());
```

In all of my attempts it appears that my `char array` always ends up empty, even though I seem to be following many examples I have found.  I dont necessarily need to use a `string` either, I just need a way of being able to pass a variable to the function, since it may not always be the same.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code here, except that it doesn't compile, run, and demonstrate the problem. On the other hand, it seems unduly complicated. The whole point of `c_str()` is that you can call a function with the result: `my_func(example.c_str());`.

Comment: It looks like you are doing the right thing; you might need to post the code of the function you are passing the char array into and tell us what makes you thing it is empty.

Comment: If you don't like the `c_str()` method, try the `data()` method.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews For that matter, `&example[0]` will work in practice and in C++11.

Comment: Your code [works for me](http://ideone.com/kfuLBZ)

Comment: Thank you all, it appears that it may have been a scoping issue.  It appeared blank because the string, as seen from that location (not shown in my example), was blank.